# img.onload not working in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, promise, onload

I am developing a react application, where I have to create an image.

I have a function that needs the image, so that it can be downloaded:

```
const handleDownloadPngGraph = async (chart, fileName) => {
  // etc.

  const imgDataUrl = await svgToImgDataURL(chartSVG, width, height, 'png')
  downloadWithLink(imgDataUrl, fileName)
}
```

I create a canvas object, just to populate the image. The part that is not working is in the `img.onload`

```
export const svgToImgDataURL = (svg, width, height, imgFormat) => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    canvas.width = width
    canvas.height = height
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

    ctx.fillStyle = variables.paletteWhite
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)

    const xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg)
    const dataUrl = `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${encodeURIComponent(xml)}`
    const img = new Image(width, height)

    img.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
      const imageData = canvas.toDataURL(`image/${imgFormat}`, 1.0)
      resolve(imageData)
    }

    img.onerror = () => reject(new Error('failing'))
    img.src = dataUrl
  })
)
```

Internet explorer 11 says:

`Unhandled promise rejection undefined`

After some research, I found this issue in GitHub:

https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/871

I also tried to set the src after the promise is resolved, but didn't work.

My main concern is: Is something wrong with the way I set the promise for internet explorer 11 (I checked that Promises are supported), or is this src issue with ie11?

Here the logs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @shrys there would have been syntax errors if that were the case.

Comment: on all the browsers I can download the image expect in internet Explorer. I added the logs in internet Explorer 11

Comment: image will be pulled from cache as soon as the SRC attribute get set. so try to detached the "src" assignment and code that as a separate statement. Ref: https://davidwalsh.name/image-load-event